Got wrong safe multisig status from sdk
we find a question but don't know how to solve.
we use safe-eth-py get the multisig tx status. The tx has been executed but we get wrong result from safe sdk.
https://hashkeychain-testnet-explorer.alt.technology/tx/0x6222010636e4ad96692da5fb780e8a07d936ffae11cf471e9dfb44749b7fb9c9


Thanks for reaching out. You are correct, this is a bug on our side, the team is aware of it and working on it as we speak. I cannot give you an estimate date of when it will be fixed, but will notify you here when it will be the case.
Thank you for your patience while we are working on fixing the issue 
Best, Louis
